# Конвертирование словаря в строки или действия со словарями на языке Python

Tags: python

У меня есть лог файл сохраненный в таком виде(кажется это тип словарь) файл содержиться 
x=open("/var/log/iptraf/sumlog")

```
['58']
['154']
['59']
['155']
```

Обычная арифметика типо ['58']+['154']+['59']+['155']=['426'] не получиться.
Хотел спросить нельзя ли конвертировать выше упомянутый список в обычные числа либо строки, чтобы потом можно было осуществить с ними действия. Скрипт нужен на питоне.
То есть получить нужно следующее:
сохранить нужно сюда q=open("/var/log/iptraf/last","w")

```
58
154
59
155
```

После чего мы бы смогли их сложить  и получить в результате сумму всех чисел, задача не сложная, но не знаю как можно это произвести.

Я попробовал написать так

```
x=open("/var/log/iptraf/sumlog")
q=open("/var/log/iptraf/last","w")
txt=x.read()
res=[]
for i in txt.split():
    res.append(int(i[2:-2]))
summ=0
for i in res:
    summ+=i
    q.write('%s\n' %summ)
```

Исправил строчку он преобразовал но не правильно первый столбец оригинал второй после преобразования

```
['58']        58
['154']       212
['59']        271
['155']       426
```

Я даже не смог уловить нить почему так произошло

Comment: Потому что Вы читаете только одно число
    
    txt=x.readline()
а не
    
    txt=x.readlines()

Comment: Изменил как вы и сказали txt=x.readlines() ошибка AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: > Я даже не смог уловить нить почему так
> произошло

['58']        58
['154']       212 = 58 + 154
['59']        271 = 59 + 212
['155']       426 = 155 + 271

происходит по тому что вы так написали в скрипте 
summ+=i # приплюсовать значение i к значению summ

Comment: хм..а ведь точно. Спасибо что пояснили учту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно еще проще, с помощью регулярного выражения

```
import re
# данные, которые берете с файла
txt="['58']\n['154']\n['59']\n['155']"
# выбирает все цифры из строки
mas = re.findall('\d+', txt)
# суммирует все числа
print sum([int(m) for m in mas])
```

Comment: А я и забыл про **sum**, хорошая функция

Comment: Еврика, спасибо тебе большое человек работает). Спасибо всем кто откликнулся очень помогли сам бы не до думался.

Comment: Если все получилось, то закрывай вопрос выбором правильного ответа или лучшего.

Comment: эмм не подскажете как его закрыть я проголосовал за ответ,а как закрыть понять не могу

Comment: Ниже иконок голосования, будет круглая иконка)

Comment: да да я ее как раз прочел, думал что проголосовать еще не значит закрыть вопрос. Понял что вопрос закрывается голосованием за тот или иной ответ. Отметил как правильный ответ. Спасибо за содействие!

Comment: На заметку, еще работаешь со строками, то лучше всего обращайся к регулярным выражениям http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: учту и запомню спасибо за совет. Редко встретишь кто поможет да еще и посоветует.)

Comment: Пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 1):

Решение задачи в лоб: извлекаем данные и помещаем их в массив

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
txt="['58']\n['154']\n['59']\n['155']" # или любой другой способ получения данных
res=[int(i[2:-2]) for i in txt.split('\n')]
summ=sum(res)
print summ
```

Результат

```
426
```